# Elasticsearch count occurrences of a value in a nested document

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to count how many times a specific value in a nested type (for instance `services.service: "map"`) can be found on all of the documents?

A document can look like this:

```
{
  "services": [
    {
      "service": "map",
      "version": 2,
      "provider": "none"
    },
    {
      "service": "map",
      "version": 0,
      "provider": "none"
    },
    {
      "service": "language",
      "version": 2,
      "provider": "none"
    }
  ],
  "date": "2019-04-26T19:17:20.197Z"
}
```

Using this mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "stat": {
      "properties": {
        "services": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "version": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "provider": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "service": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "date": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got as far as returning the count per document (see query below) but I prefer to get the final amount of occurrences summing values from all of my documents.

```
{
 "query": {
   "nested": {
     "path": "services",
     "query": {
         "match" : {
             "services.service" : "map"
         }
     },
     "inner_hits": {
       "_source" : false,
       "docvalue_fields" : ["services.service.keyword"]
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to use a nested aggregation in combination with the terms aggregation, since your fields are of type keyword. You can add the include property to the aggregation to only get the bucket of a specific value (or multiple, when passed as an array).

The query for the case you posted would look like this:

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "services": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "services"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "service_count": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "services.service",
            "include": "map"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To read more about nested aggregations, [see the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for the query and the explanation. It works as expected!